# Cannot share a photo to Messanger iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to share a photo to Messanger but it fails without returning any error.

But if I create a link instead of photo it works successfully.

```
  photo.image = image
  photo.isUserGenerated = true
  let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
  content.photos = [photo]
  FBSDKMessageDialog.show(with: content, delegate: nil)
```

Comment: Using `FBSDKMessengerSharer.share(image, with: nil)` instead of `FBSDKMessageDialog.show(with: content, delegate: nil)` will do the work.